# In a for loop how to pass parameter of function invoked by document.getElementById('').onClick

Tags: javascript

When I click on the div element I want to alert the id of div I clicked on. But on all the div elements it is alerting the last value of array i.e. 'e1'.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body  onload="populate();">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function populate() {

        var divArray = ["a1", "b1", "c1", "d1", "e1"];
        for (var x in divArray) {
            if (divArray[x] === 'a1')
                document.getElementById(divArray[x]).innerHTML = "aaaaa";
            else
                document.getElementById(divArray[x]).innerHTML = "Common";

            document.getElementById(divArray[x]).onclick = function() {
                getDiv(divArray[x]);
            };
        }
    }

    function getDiv(x)
    {
        alert(x);
    }

    </script>
    <div id="a1"></div>
    <div id="b1"></div>
    <div id="c1"></div>
    <div id="d1"></div>
    <div id="e1"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: also see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `x` is not the `x` you're hoping for.  This might help.

```
// ...
document.getElementById(divArray[x]).onclick = (function(n) {
    return function() {
        getDiv(divArray[n]);
    };
}(x));
// ...
```

Comment: or he could just use bind, as in `.onclick = getDiv.bind(null, divArray[x]);`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 1):

Replace `getDiv(divArray[x])` with `getDiv(this.id)`, as you want to return the ID of the clicked element.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your for-loop has already ended by the time you actually click the div, so x is whatever it was when the loop ended. 
To fix this, you need to call `getDiv(this.id);`

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the click event (e) into your click handler

```
        document.getElementById(divArray[x]).onclick = function(e) {
            console.log(e.toElement.id);
        };
```